# can't get higher Training Accuracy with Semi-Supervised Learning

Tags: machine-learning, semi-supervised-learning

I am currently training my model using a combination of labeled and unlabeled samples in the realm of semi-supervised learning. However, as I evaluate the model's training accuracy on labeled samples during each epoch, it rises from 20% to 50%, only to plateau at 50% for the remainder of the training process. Despite employing a cosine scheduler, achieving a higher training accuracy on labeled samples remains elusive.